# Remove all double quotes inside a string except the external

Tags: regex, csv, sed

If i have a string like below

`"firstname surname"""`

How do i remove all the internal double quotes but keeping the surounding quotes.

The reason why i want to keep the surrounding is because this string has a comma contained and don't want this to be taken as a new column in a CSV

I've tried using

```
echo '"firstname surname"""' | sed -e "s/\"\"\+/ /g"
```

But always removes the closing double quotes.

Comment: Do you want to delete all double double quotes (as answers are doing) or all double quotes not being in the edges of the string?

Comment: All double quotes not being in the edges of a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is too much sed for this, but I got this way:

```
$ echo '"firstname surname"""' | sed -e 's/^"/@/' -e 's/"$/@/' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/@/"/g'
"firstname surname"
```

Which deletes all `"` in between leading and closing `"`:

```
$ echo '"firstn"ame "surname"""' | sed -e 's/^"/@/' -e 's/"$/@/' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/@/"/g'
"firstname surname"
```

#### Explanation

```
sed     -e 's/^"/@/'    -e 's/"$/@/'           -e 's/"//g'    -e 's/@/"/g'
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^
       replace leading and closing " with @    delete all "    set @ back to "
```

Comment: What if string contains `@` as a content. e.g. mail address?

Comment: Yes... I guess the OP should have to use another strange character. As the answer was accepted, I guess this workaround was enough for the purpose, although it is *just* a workaround, would like to see what `sed` expression could make it.

Answer (score 3):

This is one situation where perl command line is more suitable than sed since lookarounds aren't supported in `sed`:

```
s='"firstname surname"foo"bar"'
echo "$s"| perl -pe 's/(?!^)"(?!$)//g'

"firstname surnamefoobar"
```

Comment: @fedorqui: lol :) since I don't know perl. I just know how to use perl command line to use complex PCRE regex that are not supported in sed

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$ echo '"firstname surname"""' | sed -e 's/["]["]//g' 
"firstname surname"
```

Comment: what is input is: `"firstname surname"foo""`

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
echo '"firstname surname"""' | awk '{gsub(/""/,x)}1'
"firstname surname"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/["]\{2,\}/"/g'
```

Remove all occurence of more than 1 " (the `["]\{2,\}` ) by only one ". It can be also used in case where sourrounding quote are not the first and last char of the full string to treat.

if it is only external quote to keep just

```
sed 's/^[^"].*[^"]$/&/;t;s/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/;s/"//g;s/.*/"&"/'
```

this insure also that we don't modify " for string that are NOT surrounded by quote

if you have your quoted string into another context, just give us a sample (especialy for delimiters info)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^("[^"]*)"(.*")$/\1\2/;ta' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/"//g;s/.*/"&"/' file
```

Comment: Mmmm I guess this assumes that the double quotes always exist in the beginning and the end of the string. It looks nice, though.